# Outlook Modifying Attachment Metadata

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, metadata, attachments

I received an email in Outlook from an external domain with five .png files as attachments. When I press save all, the metadata shows the "created" equals the time I received the email, and the "modified" equals the time I saved the file to my disk.

If I forward this email to myself however, and then do a "save all" of these exact same attachments.  Then the "created" stays the same (date email was received) but the "modified date" actually shows the correct date the png was in fact originally made.

Any ideas on how to capture the "correct" metadata without forwarding all emails to myself?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a lot and found that I have the same issue as you. When saving attachments from messages, the modified data and accessed data of these attachments will be automatically modified. However, I have not found more ways to slove it so far.

It is suggested to vote for it via Outlook UserVoice and hope this issue can be resolved soon. https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/33556420-saving-attached-as-file-creation-date-not-the-user